# downgrade Qt5.14 for Android 4.4.4,API19?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

Maybe this is a beginners question, but I really got stuck.

My first approach was to install qt5.5 (which comes with ubuntu16), but never got it run with sdktools, platformtools & ndk. Obviously I ended up here in a mess of incompatible versions.

On the other hand I installed qt5.14.0 which runs more or less "out of the box" after installing SDK & NDK.
According to Qtcreator Android settings are OK. (SDK Version: 26.1.1, NDK Version: 21.0.6113669)

As I know, the minimum level for publishing in Googlestore is Android10,API29 - this might be the reason why API19 is not of interest any more...

Do I have to downgrade to e.g. Qt5.9 or whatever? 
Many thanks in advance! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Edit your `AndroidManifest.xml` to set the target and minimum required API version for your application. Qt Creator has an [editor](https://positronicsengineer.files.wordpress.com/2019/03/android-manifest-1.png) for it.

Comment: Qt 5.14 requires API 21, same for 5.13. The docs for 5.12 suggest API 16 as minimum requirement, so that should be your best bet. I’d recommend to use the latest Qt version possible when working with mobile platforms. You might have to use an old NDK (r15e) with older Qt.

Comment: Many thanks @ Pedro & Frank! I grabbed again into the Qt-docs and it seems that Qt 5.12 supports building Android only for Win7 but not for Ubuntu. Now I'm trying to get a Win7 machine running for installing 5.12 there. The other option could be 5.14 and upgrading my phone to Android5,API21 ... I'll leave comment. Thanks again.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Qt 5.12.6 seems to work both on Windows 7 SP1 and Ubuntu 16 LTS for API 18 after installing into a "virgin" OS. The reason for my troubles with up- & downgrading Qt might be of interest for others:  Uninstalling Qt will leave some configuration files in folders `~/.config/Qt` and `~/.config/QtProject`. Deleting these folders prior to a new installation will avoid autodetecting nonexistent compilers & misconfigurated toolchains.